# Effective way of doing a rails search query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a newbie to rails. I've done a search query

`myresult = Model1.includes(':model2', ':model3').where("model1.field1 LIKE ? OR model1.    field2  LIKE ? OR model2.field1 LIKE ? OR model2.field2 LIKE ? OR model2.field3 LIKE ? OR model3.field1 LIKE ? " value1, value1, value2, value2, value3, value4 ).select("model1.field1, ..., model1.fieldn, model2.field1.., model3.field2 ")`

Now I hear this is not a good practice. Other one I found is someone said to use joins of Arel. But Arel seems to be relatively new and for me it looked like SQL-injection prone. Can  some one suggest a good way of doing this in ruby on rails.

Thank you
Sai

Comment: both model2 and model3 have a has many relation and this query works fine. I only want a better way to implement this in rails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to do full-text search across several fields, you don't want to do this in SQL.

You should use a speciallized full text search system like Sphinx or Solr.

Check out Thinking Sphinx (Rails Sphinx API):

http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/

Comment: Thank you for the comments. The application that I do is I don't own its architecture, so implementing sphinx would be difficult for me. Also, forgot to highlight the restriction I've is we are not touching the  models. Only way seems to be Arel as @allesklar said just for my module...!

Comment: Hey Sai, if you're an employee or a consultant this is the time to push back - "ur doin it wrong" - You can hack this together with the constraints you've got but it's going to cause you more pain down the road than using the right tool for this job.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You are fighting the framework. Arel is the way to go in order to do the query the Rails way which is your question.

Arel is not SQL-injection prone when you use it properly. You need to check out this page: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Create some scopes in your model and chain them together to create your query.

But as Winfield said, better use Sphinx or Soir to do some efficient full text search.